# Get relationship items that were created today?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return the amount of members that were created today, like so.

```
class CollectionResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'member_count_today' => $this->items()->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->count(),
        ];
    }
}
```

I get the error message,

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: I think you will have to specify which created_at you will take. I guess items and collectionressource both have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have tow issues in your code:

first you should determine in what table the column 'created_at' is, because you have more than a column with this name in many tables ...

second: in your comparison, you should compare between date and date, while you now are comparing date with dateTime ...

with these two notes, your code will look like:

```
  'member_count_today' => $this->items()->whereDate('members.created_at', 
  Carbon::today()->toDateString())->count();
```

please replace the table name 'members' by your db table  real name

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm guessing the members in members.created_at is the name of the relationship? The relationship inside the Collection model ($this->items) is called items. I tried your code with `items.created_at` and it tells me there is no such column. The full message is `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.created_at' in 'where clause'` and the code is ` 'member_count_today' => $this->items()->whereDate('items.created_at', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->count(),`

Comment: no, it's not the name of the relation, it's the name of the db table name that hold members information, maybe users ...